# Sending POST REQUEST from FIREBASE isnt working

Tags: javascript, firebase, post, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-functions

im trying to send a post request from my firebase function but the post request never runs. In the firebase console everything seems to be fine.

```js
  var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "key="+ key);
  let res = {
   "notification": {
    "title": "Test",
    "body": "Notificación enviada desde Firebase"
   },
   "to": to,
  }
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(res))
  console.log(xhttp)
  return (xhttp);
```

i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: Maybe this will be of use [How Firebase Cloud functions handle HTTP post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42995433/387194)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to implement in your code the logic for when the request is finished as it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST), so you can debug what is being sent by the server you're trying to send this request.

Finally, if you are not very familiar XMLHttpRequest, you could give it a try to axios in your firebase functions (Promise based HTTP client),

```
axios.post('/your_endoint', {
    param1: 'hello',
    param2: 'there'
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

to see more details for axios config you can visit the [Github page](https://github.com/axios/axios) details